# Angular 2 with Google Drive Realtime API

Tags: angular, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm looking to create a new application based on the **Drive Realtime API** and want to do it with the shiny new **Angular 2** framework.  However, I'm kind of stuck trying to figure out how to best integrate the APIs and philosophies.  I can't find *any* examples that use both.

What is the best way to get these two frameworks working together. In particular, how do I reconcile the differences between Angular's two way binding with [ngModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel) and the Realtime APIs data binding with [gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.Binding](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.Binding)?

Answer (score 3):

You can download the declaration file (*.d.ts) for the Google Drive Realtime API [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/google-drive-realtime-api). This provides a TypeScript wrapper for the API. Specifically, it defines a module named `gapi.drive.realtime` whose classes can be accessed in Angular2.

To tell the compiler about the declaration file, you need to add the following line to your TypeScript source file:

```
///<reference path="google-drive-realtime-api.d.ts" />
```

Then you need to import the module's features. One way to do this is with the following `import` command:

```
import * as Drive from "gapi.drive.realtime";
```

Then you can access the module's classes under the `Drive` namespace: `Drive.Collaborator`, `Drive.CollaborativeObject`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm familiar with using type definitions and importing with System.js.  Mine is not a simple _'how to use an ES5 library in Typescript?'_ question. My question is more about reconciling the differences between the approaches, such as with data binding.  I'm sure I could hack it to get it working, but am looking for thoughts, experience and patterns on how best use a library with collaboration usage constraints in an environment like Angular 2.

Comment: @MattScarpino do we need to npm install google drive api?

Comment: @MattScarpino: Where should the reference be added ? I did `npm install' but was not able to understand as to where the reference needs to be added.