# Need google-drive-realtime-api tuotorial with angular2

Tags: angular, google-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am new to angular2. I want to use google-drive-realtime-api in my project. And got it from the npm : `npm install --save @types/google-drive-realtime-api`

Is there a good tutorial or quick start with realtime api in anuglar2?

> PS:
>   [Angular 2 with Google Drive Realtime API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374878/angular-2-with-google-drive-realtime-api)
>   this is not what I am looking for.